# How can I Write this in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

```
if ( !document.getElementById('chkBoxView').checked
    &&!document.getElementById('chkBoxEdit').checked
    &&!document.getElementById('chkBoxAdd').checked
    &&!!document.getElementById('chkBoxDelete').checked )
{
    alert('Please select atleast one checkBox');
    return false;
}
else {
 // Atleast One Check Box Selected By User.
 return true
}
```

Above is JavaScript, What can be the Corresponding & Optimized code in JQuery ?

Comment: @ceejayoz Not A Problem.But JQuery being a library or framework of JS can have some more built in Function,which i intend to use..

Comment: is the same, only change e.g. document.getElementById('chkBoxView').checked  to ->> $('#chkBoxView').checked

Comment: jQuery is great, but it's important to understand that using jQuery to do that is *not* "optimized".  What you already have is faster and more efficient than any implementation using jQuery for the selection.

Comment: @Dave Ward is correct, though for something this short I doubt that there would be any major difference in execution speed between the native code and the jQuery equivalent. I think from the answers below you may find the jQuery code is easier to maintain. If you had hundreds of checkboxes, it would certainly might a difference. For me personally, the performance loss in the browser is almost always offset by a big performance gain in development and maintenance, otherwise I wouldn't use jQuery at all. When in doubt, I write the script twice and go with the best one (not always the fastest).

Comment: True, the jQuery could be more concise and maintainable; no argument there.  I pointed out the performance difference because he mentioned that he wanted to "optimize" the native code, as though less code necessarily runs faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!$(":checkbox[id^=chkBox]:checked").length) {
    alert('Please select atleast one checkBox');
    return false;
}
alert('you filled at least one!');
return true;
```

Since all of your checkbox IDs start with 'chkBox' you can address them using the [attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). A truthy length of checked checkboxes means at least one has been checked.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/KSjSH/2/

Comment: In this,I guess Id should be numeric or sequencial or else it might not work ??

Comment: No, [id^=chkBox] means match *all* elements whose IDs begin with chkBox. IDs should never be duplicated, and based on your posted markup, the above solution should work just fine.

Comment: @Pratik - I failed to correctly understand your question. Have updated my answer. It should make more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (
    !jQuery('#chkBoxView').is(':checked')
    &&!jQuery('#chkBoxEdit').is(':checked')
    &&!jQuery('#chkBoxAdd').is(':checked')
    &&!jQuery('#chkBoxDelete').is(':checked')
    ) {
    alert('Please select atleast one checkBox');
    return false;
}
else {
 // Atleast One Check Box Selected By User.
 return true
}
```

if you prefer `$` over `jQuery` you can use that one as well ofc.

Comment: there's no need to use the selector :checked, $().checked will return true if checked

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("input:checked[id=yourid]").val()
```

This is good way

```
jQuery('#chkBoxView').is(':checked')
```

Comment: This is for getting the value, but that is not what the OP wants to do. Please reread the question (besides that, this seems to be an inefficient selector).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multiple selector to get each of the checkboxes if it's checked, and then check that the length of the result is not zero:

```
if (!$('#chkBoxView:checked,#chkBoxEdit:checked,#chkBoxAdd:checked,#chkBoxDelete:checked').length) {
  alert('Please select at least one checkBox');
  return false;
} else {
  // At least One Check Box Selected By User.
  return true;
}
```